# $_SESSION not work recalled dynamically with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

Good evening.
This is my code:

Page js.js

```
window.setInterval(function () {
$.ajax({
        async: true,
        cache:false,
        type: 'POST',
        url:'call.php',
        data:{
            request: 'validation_session'
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(item,key){
            console.log(item);
        },
        error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
    });
},3000);
```

Page Call.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['request'])){
         $_SESSION['test']['test1'] = true;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['test']['test1'])){
       echo 'okay';
     }

?>
```

This code is a small representation of my real code but the $_session is't created why?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: You're missing a curly bracket at the end of the JS, just before the semicolon (;). Maybe that's the error.

Comment: Question 1, is the PHP even getting called? This is basic troubleshooting to perform with your browser inspector before posting a question. PHP and JavaScript are two very different things.

Comment: No, it's my error of rewrite of code.

Comment: @miken32 My php is called with ajax and when load page.

Comment: It's supposed to be called, or you have confirmed that it is callled? And if it is, does it output what you expect?

Comment: I confirm that php is called because if i add an echo inside if($_POST...), this return on js console log

Comment: my guess is that you output something before the session_start();, could be white character before <?php

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer. Can you put a code please?

Comment: "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser." from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I don't think any sessions are set, so the if statement would obviously not work. Make sure to set session and then perform the checks.

Comment: The session is started because if I declare a session variable outside the if, it's printed.